# REST status code for batch query with partial result

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes, openapi

I'm creating a REST API where the client can query for data for certain ids. An example query looks like:

```
/api/data?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3&start=2019-01-01&end=2019-02-12
```

This follows the Open API spec for passing an array: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters

Suppose now that ids 2 and 3 exist and return 1 record and 0 records respectively. Suppose also that id 1 does not exist.

What should be returned to the client? I'm leaning towards returning an OK 200 with a dictionary where id 3 will be present as a key but contain no data, whereas id 1 will not be present at all.

Something like this:

```
{
  {
    id=2,
    records=[154334, 324343]
  },
  {
    id=3,
    records=[]
  }
}
```

Then the client would have to infer that id 1 is invalid. And when trying to issue a query to retrieve metadata on id 1:

```
/api/entity/1
```

then I would return a 404 Not Found.

In general, I would like to find good solutions for handling responses and status codes to REST API requests where the query gives a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are other fields that have valid data, sending 200 would be the correct response. Inferring that data does not exist would be the client (callee's?) responsibility.

To note here: Sender's request is correct. And you also have data as per the sent filters.

From the server's POV

This is a function of type

```
GetData(
(name="id")List<int> ids, 
(name="start") DateTime startDate, 
(name="end") DateTime endDate){
           // your logic goes here
}
```

- Sender sent a request as per contract. (hence not 400)
- You as a server do have valid data to respond with with set filters (hence not 404)
- Presumably auth is setup (Hence not 401)
- You are fully processing the request (hence not 202)
- You aren't creating anything (hence not 201).